# Verify the inf of a subset S of $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Let S=$\{a_n=\frac{3n+1}{n}:n\geq 0\}$ , verify that $infS=3$. 
MY IDEA is:  $\lim_{n \to \infty }a_n=3$, so by the definition of the limit we can say: $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \bar{n}: |\frac{3n+1}{n}-3|<\epsilon$. 
Now we recall the following property of the infimum of a generic $A\subseteq \mathbb R$:
Let $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ is bounded from below, $l=infA\iff\left.\Bigg\lbrace\begin{aligned}
 & (i) l\leq a\enspace \forall a\in A \\
 &  (ii) \forall \epsilon>0\enspace \exists\enspace a \in A: l+\epsilon>a          \\
 \end{aligned}
 \right.$
The definition of limit tell us that: $-\epsilon<\frac{3n+1}{n}-3<\epsilon\Longrightarrow 3+\epsilon>\frac{3n+1}{n}$. Therefore from the property above we conclude that $infS=3$.
It's all right?

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of the infimum. Let $\inf S =x$ then by definition for all $\epsilon>0$, one needs to find a $y\in S$ such that $y < x+\epsilon.$ In other words you need to find $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n=\frac{3n+1}{n}<x+\epsilon.$ Our guess for the infimum is $x=3$ and so we need to find an $\epsilon>0$ that works. So we try, $\frac{3n+1}{n}<3+\epsilon\implies \frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ and so if we choose any $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ then we have that $a_n<3+\epsilon$ and thus $\inf S = 3.$

Comment: Ok all right. But what I would like to know is if the definition of limit suggest you that the definition of infimum is satisfied by 3, as I have tried to show.

Comment: For your case, it works because $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence. But I guess you have to justify this

Comment: @ nls But I am justifying this just observing the fact that since the limit is 3 this implies by definition of limit ($\forall \epsilon>0\exists \bar{n}: |a_n-3|<\epsilon \forall n\geq \bar{n}$) that $3+\epsilon>a_n\forall n\geq \bar{n}$, not?